# Accessing temporarily Another User's directories by entering his User ID and Password in Mac

Tags: mac, user-account

I've two user accounts in my mac, One for me and other for my friend. When friend is using the MacBook and he needs some file from me, for that I've to login into my account and share the file by file sharing or USB data traveller. It takes time. What I want is, when my friend needs some file from my account, I should just double click on a folder in finder within my account under Users and finder ask my login id and password and grant me access on entering right password. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

First, set up a shared folder on your account (or both if you need both way) so that every file you'll copy there will be visible from your friend account.
You already have a public folder which can accomplish this.
Next, you can enable fast user switch from Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options. Doing so, you'll have login controls in the right side of the menu bar. You just need to login, copy the files in the public folder and logout.

Even faster, open the Terminal (Applications > Utility > Terminal), and type

```
su YourUsername
```

it will ask for password. Enter it, and you will be logged on the shell with your account. From here, browse the folders and find the files you need (*cd foldername* to enter a folder, *cp filesource filedestination* to copy). Then logout with *exit*. Example:

```
Mac:~ Jack$ su epistrephein
Password:
bash-3.2$ cd Downloads
bash-3.2$ cp picture6.jpg ~/Public/picture6.jpg
bash-3.2$ exit
Mac:~ Jack$
```

Comment: I had been doing the same suggested in first part of reply i.e. by fast user switch. But I wanted to prevent login/logout. I just wanted that there should be some option by which one user could open other user's folder (or his own folders from other user's account) by entering his password. What had been done by terminal, is the same I want but in GUI.

Comment: Dear epistrephein, The Terminal command method you mentioned above isn't working. When I try to access download folder by the command "cd Downloads", it says, "Permission Denied" even though I used the correct credentials.

Comment: Ah, yes. You'll still be in your _own_ user's home folder. Type `cd ~` first to switch to your current (the target) user's home folder.

Answer (score -1):

Or share via Dropbox or a similar service